# Do Stephen Wolfram and Gerard 't Hooft propose that literally every cellular automaton is a universe?

Tags: cellular-automata

Both Stephen Wolfram and Nobel laureate Gerard 't Hooft think that the universe is a cellular automaton.

As far as I know, 't Hooft developed a series of frameworks to build different models of cellular automata and Wolfram also proposed a framework where network nodes could produce different cellular automaton universes.

Both of them proposed specific models of cellular automata to describe our universe (or rather they are working in a cellular automaton description that can be applied entirely to our universe), but since they proposed a framework to create different cellular automaton models, this makes me think that these authors think that literally every type of cellular automaton corresponds to a universe.

For example, apparently Stephen Wolfram in his book "A New Kind Of Science", chapter 9, he defines a series of network nodes that could be capable of reproducing all models of cellular automata. But I am not sure about this and I would need someone that knows better this field to confirm this to me.

So, does anyone here know of this is correct? Does anyone here know these works well enough to tell me if these physicists think that every cellular automaton model corresponds to a universe?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Stephen Wolfram generally doesn't know as much about Computer Science as he thinks he does.

Comment: @jmite what do you exactly mean by that?